# How to sum and remove duplicates on 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

*`Application Match` for one column works but for 2 columns is giving me error*

```
With Sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        DupRow = Application.Match(Cells(i, 9).Value, Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(i - 1, 9)), 0)
        DoEvents

        If Not IsError(DupRow) Then
            Cells(i, 8).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value + Cells(DupRow, 8).Value
            Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value + Cells(DupRow, 9).Value
            Rows(DupRow).Delete

        End If
    Next i
End With
```

*for 2 columns Error runtime 1004*

```
DupRow = Application.Match(Cells(i, 4).Value & Cells(i, 5).Value, Range(Cells(1, 4) & Cells(1, 5), Cells(i - 1, 4) & Cells(i - 1, 5)), 0)
```

*What is the correct way of doing this?*

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's better to use dictionary for that, which has built-in method for managing keys, so it can be used to get unique values:

```
Sub teest()
    Dim val As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        val = Cells(i, 1).Value & Cells(i, 2).Value
        If dict.Exists(val) Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        Else
            dict.Add val, 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```